# How can I do an efficient calculation / approximation of a set of values of a reciprocal function with as few divisions as possible?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, soft-question, approximation, computational-mathematics

I have a function of the form $$f(t) = \frac{a}{bt+c}$$
Which I want to calculate (or numerically approximate) with regular steps on an interval, let us say $$t = t_0 + (t_1-t_0)\frac{k}{N}, \forall k \in\{0,\cdots,N\}$$

The thing is I want to avoid numerical divisions as much as possible as those are slow to do with my computer. Multiplications and additions are okay. But of course I want to get away with a few of those as well (if I can!).

Answer (score 2):

To simplify, let's take $a=b=c=1$ and $t_0=0$ and $t_1=1$.

Define $s_k = \frac{k}N$. You want to evaluate $f$ at $N+1$ points $s_0,\dots,s_{N}$. To beat the direct computation, you need to do it in less than $N+1$ divisions. You don't seem to care so much about the number of additions or multiplications.

$$\begin{split}
f(s_{k+1})&=\frac 1 {1+\frac {k+1} N}\\
&=\frac 1 {1+\frac {k} N + \frac{1}N}\\
&=\frac 1 {1+\frac {k} N}\cdot \frac {1}{1+\frac{\frac 1N}{1+\frac{k}{N}}}\\
&=f(s_k)\cdot \frac {1}{1+\frac {f(s_k)}N}\\
&=f(s_k)\cdot \sum_{p\geq 0}(-1)^p\left( \frac {f(s_k)}N\right)^p \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(1)}
\end{split}$$
Truncating the sum above to the $m$-th term yields an error of $$f(s_k)\left( \frac {f(s_k)}N\right)^{m+1}\leq \frac 1 {N^{m+1}}$$
So an algorithm to estimate to a given precision $\varepsilon>0$

- **Initialization**: Compute $f(s_0)$ *[1 division]* and $\alpha=\frac 1 N$ *[1 division]*
- **Computation of $f(s_{k+1})$ given $f(s_k)$ and $\alpha$**: *[no division]*
  $$\left\{
  \begin{split}
  f(s_{k+1})&\simeq f(s_k)\cdot \sum_{p= 0}^m(-1)^p\alpha^p f(s_k)^p\\
  \text{where } & \alpha^{m+1}<\varepsilon
  \end{split}
  \right.$$

This algorithm will make you do many more additions and multiplications than the direct computation, but you seemed fine with it.

Comment: Thank you. It is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. We have the function :
$$t\to f(t) = \frac{a}{(tb+c)}$$
Consider the derivative of our function
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{-ab}{(tb+c)^2}$$
Now at first glance this may seem to not help us very much , as we also get a square on top of the reciprocal. There still is a division involved.

But assume that we at some $t_k$ have an approximation to $f(t_k)$.

We realize we can rewrite the derivative as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -\frac{b}a f(t)^2$$
Now we can now mimic the [**Euler forward scheme**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), taking small steps in the direction of the derivative.

$$f(t_k+t_\Delta) \approx f(x_k) + t_\Delta f'(x_k)$$

We see that with the substitution $k=-b/a$ (which can be pre-calculated as well) what is required to calculate by using such a scheme is two multiplications and one addition per new value (after the first).

Here is a sample run for a randomized set of {a,b,c}:

[image][image]

Comment: +1. Since multiplication is fine I suggest a small refinement and use $$\frac{16}{17}f(x) - \frac{8}{17} \frac{b}{a}\Delta_t  f(x)^2$$ instead. Didn’t explicitly check but I expect this to give better approximations overall.

Comment: @WimC Due to the monotonic nature of the derivative of this particular function and the linear nature of the additive increment I agree that some minor adjustment probably should be made. However it would be nicer to have divisibility by a power of 2. It behaves much nicer with multiplication in the arithmetics. Maybe fractions of 16 instead. The actual adjusted coefficients probably need to be tested in some simulation. Maybe carefully adjusted coefficients will let us take longer steps without going too far in the tangent direction.

Comment: These particular coefficients predict the sum of any alternating series given only its two (!) first terms. In this case the series is given in the answer of @StefanLafon. Other pretty amazing examples are $$\frac{16}{17} - \frac{8}{17}\cdot\frac13 \approx \frac{\pi}4$$ and $$\frac{16}{17} - \frac{8}{17}\cdot\frac12 \approx \log(2).$$

Comment: What? Makes no sense.

Comment: And if you go for three multiplications then $f\cdot (1 - \alpha f + (\alpha f)^2)$ from the answer by Stefan Lafon is probably a better approach anyway.